# Binary serial adder - VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to design a 32bit binary serial adder in VHDL, using a structural description. The adder should make use of a full adder and a d-latch. The way I see it is:

Full adder:

```
architecture Behavioral of FullAdder is
begin

s <= (x xor y) xor cin;
cout <= (x and y) or (y and cin) or (x and cin);
end Behavioral;
```

D-Latch:

```
architecture Behavioral of dLatch is
begin
state: process(clk)
begin
    if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
        q <= d;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Serial adder:

```
add: process ( clk )
    variable count : integer range 0 to 31;
        variable aux : STD_LOGIC;
        variable aux2 : STD_LOGIC;
    begin
        if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
        fa: FullAdder port map(x(count), y(count), aux, s(count), aux2);
                    dl: dLatch port map(clock, aux2, aux);
        count := count + 1; 
    end if;
     end process;
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.
Also, what would be the simplest way to pipeline the serial adder?

Comment: It's a bit hard to check without the entity declarations as you have used postional mapping of signals to ports.  I recommend using named port mapping (pinname => signal_name).  Have you built a simulation?  If not do so.  If you have, use it to explain to us what "it doesn't seem to work" means - what did you expect to see?  What did you actually see?

Answer (score 0):

"It doesn't seem to work" is pretty general, but one problem I see is that you are trying to instantiate the component `fa: FullAdder` within a process. Think about what component instantiation means in hardware, and you will realize that it makes no sense to instantiate the module on the rising_edge of clk...

Move the instantiation out of the process, and it should at least remove the syntax error you should be seeing ("Illegal sequential statement." in ModelSim).

Answer (score 0):

For pipelining the serial adder, the best way is to connect the adders and d flip-flops one after the other. So, you would have the cout of the first adder be the input of a flip-flop. The output of that flip-flop will be the cin of the next adder and so on. Be careful though, because you will also have to pipeline the s of each adder, as well as each bit of the input, by essentially putting several d flip-flops in a row to copy them through the various pipeline stages.