# Can I use 'port map' in a 'process'?

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- create a entity
entity ex1_3 is 
port(
    a,b,c,d: in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    ctrl: in std_logic;

    sum: out std_logic );
end ex1_3;

architecture impl of ex1_3 is

-- declare a component of four bit ripple carry adder 
component four_bit_ripple_carry_adder is
port(
    a,b: in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    cin: in std_logic;

    s:   out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    cout:out std_logic
);
end component;

signal s: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

begin

process(a,b,c,d,ctrl)
begin
-- error:Illegal sequential statement.
if ctrl = '0' then
    u0: four_bit_ripple_carry_adder port map(a,b,ctrl,s,sum);
elsif ctrl = '1' then
    u1: four_bit_ripple_carry_adder port map(c,d,ctrl,s,sum);
end if;

end architecture;
```

> ** Error: /home/atomman/drs_exercises/exercise_04/ex1_3.vhd(30): Illegal sequential statement.
>
> ** Error: /home/atomman/drs_exercises/exercise_04/ex1_3.vhd(32): Illegal sequential statement.
>
> ** Error: /home/atomman/drs_exercises/exercise_04/ex1_3.vhd(35): near "architecture": (vcom-1576) expecting PROCESS.

Comment: u0 and u1 are component instantiations - concurrent statements. In VHDL syntax a process statement can only contain sequential statements and concurrent statements are found in architecture body or block statement statement parts, or for passive process and assertion statements in an entity statement part. The intent to reflect hardware design hierarchy. Processes describe the behavior of an entity or monitor simulation. It's less hardware to multiplex the inputs to one adder than have two adders and select a set of outputs. Here, structurally described hardware not software equivalents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary serial adder - VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931436/binary-serial-adder-vhdl)

Answer (score 3):

Never forget that the "H" in HDL stands for "Hardware".

What you are saying is *"if ctrl=0 then use a piece of hardware, name it u0 which is connect as ... else replace that piece of hardware, now name it u1 and connect it as ..."*. 
There is no simple hardware equivalent that dynamically, based on a signal (in this case 'ctrl') swaps in and out two components.

The only difference is in the first two ports, which makes the solution simple:  You make one component and use a multiplexer<sup>1</sup> for the first two input ports:

```
signal a_or_c_mux: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal b_or_d_mux: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

  a_or_c_mux <= a when ctrl='0' else c;
  b_or_d_mux <= b when ctrl='0' else d;
```

Now you can instance your module (once! and outside a process) and use the signals `a_or_c_mux` and `b_or_d_mux` as input to the first two ports of the module.

<sup>1</sup><sub>On purpose I am using 'hardware' nomenclature.</sub>